# How do we resize the segmented mask to Any size using UNET Neural Network Architecture

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, image-segmentation

Objective : Is to segment out Hair Regions in any given selfi Image.

**My existing work:**

I use the UNET architecture with input image size as 128 x 128 x 3

```
#UNET Architecture
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

c1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (s)
c1 = BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
c1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
c1 = BatchNormalization()(c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = BatchNormalization()(c2)
c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
c2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
c2 = BatchNormalization()(c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
c3 = BatchNormalization()(c3)
c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
c3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
c3 = BatchNormalization()(c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
c4 = BatchNormalization()(c4)
c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
c4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
c4 = BatchNormalization()(c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
c5 = BatchNormalization()(c5)
c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
c5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)
c5 = BatchNormalization()(c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
c6 = BatchNormalization()(c6)
c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
c6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)
c6 = BatchNormalization()(c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
c7 = BatchNormalization()(c7)
c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
c7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)
c7 = BatchNormalization()(c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
c8 = BatchNormalization()(c8)
c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
c8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)
c8 = BatchNormalization()(c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
c9 = BatchNormalization()(c9)
c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
c9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)
c9 = BatchNormalization()(c9)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
```

**Result:**

[![Result of the segmentation][1]][1]

The model had learned very well and able to mask-out perfectly for ***128 x 128 x 3.***

**Problem statement:**

But for my end application I need an resolution exactly ***600 x 600 resolution*** (as my segmented output mask) from the UNET Architecture. How should I do it? If its not possible, then how can I  get closer enough to get higher mask size like ***572 x 572*** ?

Any help or suggestions would be of a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did my answer prove to be helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

The UNet model takes input sizes which need to be divisible with `32`. You cannot change that however. `572` is not divisible by `32`, but it is by `576`, which is the closest.

In my opinion, you should train with `608x608`, since `608` is closer to `600` than `576`.

At the same time, downsampling from `608x608` to `600x600` produces less visible distortions than upsampling from `576x576` ---> `600x600`.

The easiest solution is to train on `608x608` and then downsample to `600x600`. Use the `cv2.INTER_AREA` to downsample both the output image and the segmented result.

> INTER_AREA – resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a
> preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free
> results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to
> the INTER_NEAREST method.

Of course, in order to train with a specific resolution you need to change the parameters in the first layer:

```
inputs = Input((576, 576, 3))
```

Comment: but do you know what needs to be changed in the above code, inorder to get 576 output mask from the UNET Architecture ?

Comment: inputs = Input((576, 576, 3))